# Locus of centroid of a $\triangle{ABC}$ with $A=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$, $B=(\sin\alpha,-\cos\alpha)$, and $C=(1,2)$

Tags: triangles, locus, centroid, triangle-centres

> If $A(\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)$, $B(\sin\alpha, -\cos\alpha)$ and $C(1,2)$ are the vertices of $\triangle ABC$, find the locus of the triangle's centroid as $\alpha$ varies.

---

Let centroid be $(h,k)$,
$$(h,k)\equiv\left(\frac{\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\alpha) + 1}{3},\frac{\sin(\alpha) - \cos(\alpha) + 2}{3}\right)\tag{1}$$
How to proceed further? Hints would be appreciated!

---

As suggested by @wonderman

From $(1)$,
$$\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\alpha) = 3h - 1 \qquad \sin(\alpha) - \cos(\alpha) = 3k - 2$$ 
When we square the above and add,
$$ (3h - 1)^2 + (3k - 1)^2 = 2$$
Substituting $h$ as $x$ and $k$ as $y$,
$$3x^2 + 3y^2 - 2h - 4k + 1 = 0$$

Comment: Your (h,k) is incorrect from the given

Comment: Thanks! I wrote the coordinates of the vertex A wrong. Fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $(\sin \alpha + \cos \alpha)^2 + (\sin \alpha - \cos \alpha)^2$.  What does this work out to?

Comment: please check PS.

Answer (score 0):

The centroid of $ABC$ lies on the segment joining $C$ with the midpoint $M$ of $AB$, precisely at $\frac{2}{3}$ of such segment. 
In your problem $M$ travels from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ and $C$ is fixed, so the locus of centroids is a segment with endpoints $(-1/3,2/3)$ and $(1,2/3)$.